# d3.js on "click" event handling running function without click event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently doing mouse click event handling for my d3 visualization:

```
fooCircle.on("click",fooFunction("barParameter"));
```

My problem is that the function is ran without me having to click on the element. I know this because I put print statements within the function.

Interestingly, when I change the function to not be a function that takes in any parameters, the function behaves has it should, meaning it gets ran when I click on the appropriate element:

```
fooCircle.on("click",fooFunction);
```

Answer (score 10):

Someone helped me with the problem. The solution is do:

```
fooCircle.on("click", function () {fooFunction("barParameter"); });
```

This way, a function is passed into the on function, as opposed to the result of a function.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, because you're calling `fooFunction` at the place where you're subscribing to the click handler:

```
fooCircle.on("click",fooFunction("barParameter"));// Calls fooFunction with param "barParameter"
```

At that moment, you see your console.log, because you've just called the function.

Furthermore, I assume your `fooFunction` doesn't return anything, which essentially means it returns `undefined`. So then the subscription essentially becomes:

```
fooCircle.on("click", undefined);// Nothing will happen since there's no handler
```

That's why the second code snippet works as it should; because you're providing it with a function to call later.

A question remains though, what is the significance of `"barParameter"`? Do you have a need to pass some other parameter into `fooFunction` – other than `d` and `i` which d3 will provide when it calls the handler on click?

Comment: I guess I could use d instead of "barParameter" if I give the element the necessary information by using the datum, data, or enter functions. Currently in my D3 code, the element in question does not have the said information. Either way is fine. It just depends on how one thinks which way is clearer for code readability.

Comment: @meetamit Your answer gives useful information. I'm also having the same problem. If I take the same code snippet, yes I need to pass some variable to `fooFunction`. How can I do that?

Comment: @RAS I think tmnt-rafael's answer below addresses what you're asking. If you want to get fancier, you can read about [partial application of functions](http://raganwald.com/2013/03/07/currying-and-partial-application.html).

Comment: @meetamit tmnt-rafel's answer definitely solves the problem but my problem is that I can't write inline function.

Comment: @RAS Not sure exactly what you mean. You can post it as a question, with example code.