# D3 Click event not working on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js, mouseevent

I am having trouble getting a google map to recognize clicks. Everything else is working and the circles are displaying correctly. But when I click on a circle the cursor does not change from a hand and if I click on it the console.log does not get invoked.

Any suggestions?

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" /><script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>    <script src="/mydrupal/sites/default/d3_files/d3.v3.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">svg {
border:0px solid #ebebeb;
}
.members, .members svg {
 position: absolute;
}
.members svg {
width: 60px;
height: 20px;
padding-right: 100px;
font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.members circle {
fill: brown;
stroke: black;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
#map {
width: 960px;
height: 700px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
</style>
<div id="map">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function prettyAlert(p_message, p_title) {
p_title = p_title || "";
$(p_message).dialog({
   title: p_title,
   width:400,
   height:400,
   resizable: false,
   modal : true,
   overlay: { 
     backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.5 
     },
   close: function(ev, ui) {
     $(this).remove(); 
     }
 });
}
var cx; var cy;
var width  = 1000;
var height = 800;

// Create the Google Map…
var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map") .node(), {
zoom: 11, 
center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.7, -79.4),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN // was ROADMAP
}
); // end new map
var circles;

var imageAttributes = {height:32, width:32, x:-16, y:-16};

d3.json("http://localhost:8888/mydrupal/member-json?nocache=" + (new Date()).getTime(),function(error,members){
 var bottom=members.organizations.map(function(members) {
    return members.member;
  });

var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
// Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
overlay.onAdd = function() {
var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes() .overlayMouseTarget)
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "members")
    ; // end var layer

// Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
// We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
overlay.draw = function() {
  var projection = this.getProjection(),
      padding = 10; // end var projection

  var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
      .data(bottom)
      .each(transform) // update existing markers
    .enter()
      .append("svg:svg")
      .each(transform)
      .attr("class", "marker")
  ; // end var marker

 // Add a label.
  marker.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", padding + 7)
      .attr("y", padding)
      .attr("dy", ".31em")
     .on("click", function(bottom) {
        console.log("click"); //not happening
        var message="<div><span style ='float: left; margin:0 7px 50px 0; height:50px;'><img src="+bottom.image+" style='width:50px; height:50px;' /></span>"+ bottom.body + "<br /><a href='http://" + bottom.field_url + "' target=_blank><u>" + bottom.field_url + "</u></a></div>";
        prettyAlert(message, bottom.title);
        })
      .on("touchstart", function(bottom) {
        console.log("click"); //not happening
         var message="<div><span style ='float: left; margin:0 7px 50px 0; height:50px;'><img src="+bottom.image+" style='width:50px; height:50px;' /></span>"+ bottom.body + "<br /><a href='http://" + bottom.field_url + "' target=_blank><u>" + bottom.field_url + "</u></a></div>";
    prettyAlert(message, bottom.title);
       })
      .text(function(bottom) { 
            return bottom.title; 
           })
; // end text marker append
  // Add a circle.
  marker.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .attr("cx", padding)
      .attr("cy", padding)
      .on("click", function(bottom) {
        console.log("click"); //not happening
        var message="<div><span style ='float: left; margin:0 7px 50px 0; height:50px;'><img src="+bottom.image+" style='width:50px; height:50px;' /></span>"+ bottom.body + "<br /><a href='http://" + bottom.field_url + "' target=_blank><u>" + bottom.field_url + "</u></a></div>";
        prettyAlert(message, bottom.title);
        })
      .on("touchstart", function(bottom) {
        console.log("click"); //not happening
         var message="<div><span style ='float: left; margin:0 7px 50px 0; height:50px;'><img src="+bottom.image+" style='width:50px; height:50px;' /></span>"+ bottom.body + "<br /><a href='http://" + bottom.field_url + "' target=_blank><u>" + bottom.field_url + "</u></a></div>";
    prettyAlert(message, bottom.title);
       })
  ; // end marker append circle

  function transform(bottom) {
    bottom = new google.maps.LatLng(bottom.field_lat, bottom.field_lng);
    bottom = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(bottom);
    return d3.select(this)
        .style("left", (bottom.x - padding) + "px")
        .style("top", (bottom.y - padding) + "px");
   } // end transform 
 }; // end overlay draw
}; // end overlay add function

// Bind our overlay to the map…
overlay.setMap(map); 
}); //  end members json
</script>
```

Comment: As it is your function is being called at the time you are subscribing to the click handler. You want to pass just the function name and declare it elsewhere. You can check whether that is happening by looking to see if the console message gets logged when you initialize your graph.

Comment: I don't understand which function you are referring to.

Comment: `.on("click", function(bottom) {...` This function is not being called when you click...it is called earlier at startup...it will need to be `on("click",doSomething)`...here you should just pass the function name.

Comment: [An example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483995/d3-js-on-click-event-handling-running-function-without-click-event) of what I think is happening. The beginning of the answer by @meetamit is the point I am trying to make.

Comment: I used exactly the same approach for a similar map which used a geo map instead of a google map. It worked correctly then. Is this different for a google map?

Comment: No, it shouldn't...hopefully I have not brought confusion into this. Is the console.log message not firing at all? If I am right, it should be firing at startup...before any user interaction.

Comment: The console.log was not firing at all. I followed your advice and created a separate function but it is getting fired on mouse scrolling events and still not on clicks.

Comment: To be honest, I had promised myself to be wary of examples I cannot replicate in a fiddle...it can turn into a shooting in the dark. Any chance you could put the JSON input as a javascript variable and create a fiddle? It would help folks help you more effectively. Right now I am not helping you much and it is not a good thing. And we can enlist @LarsKotthoff to help us out...the man!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48629/discussion-between-patriciaw-and-fernoftheandes)

Comment: With a considerable amount of assistance from FernOfTheAndes I have a working map, with images instead of circles, clicking brings up a dialog box and hovering over an image displays the title. The working script is here http://jsfiddle.net/PatriciaW/aDvSp/